# Unable to play you-tube videos in live website

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I created a youtube video gallery in my webpage. Every thing works fine in locally. But when uploaded to server youtube videos are not playing. When i check the console it shows that

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.thecrazymind.net/popmedia/#' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/S8suc_C8J94?rel=1&autoplay=1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

My website link is

> https://www.thecrazymind.net/popmedia/#

Comment: try to call the video trought https://

Comment: this is the url iuse to call video https://youtu.be/fM1iH1R_Z_0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your website is using https (and probably not your local), so loading content without encryption cause security issue and the browser block the content.

You must use https URL for your video.

-- edit --

Look like prettyphoto plugin replace youtube url, and load http by default. By changing :

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/
```

to

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/
```

in jquery.prettyPhoto.js will do the trick

Comment: i am using  https url

Comment: look like a prettyPhoto 'bug', check the"jquery.prettyPhoto.js" and change the " http ://www.youtube.com/embed/ " to " https ://www.youtube.com/embed/ "